# Windsor circular dependency of a transient-lifestyle component

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, circular-dependency, castle

I've got a bunch of classes written like this:

```
public class MyService1 {
    public MyService1(MyService1Settings settings, <service-dependent list of dependencies filled by Windsor>) { ... }
}
```

which are registered in the Windsor like this:

```
container.Register(
    ...
    Component.For<MyService1>().LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<MyService2>().LifestyleTransient(),
    ...
);
```

container doesn't have any of the `MyServiceXSettings` types registered, so the only way to get a service is to resolve it from container like this:

```
TService service = windsorContainer.Resolve<TService>(new { settings });
```

The thing is, depending on the parameters in the `settings` object, one of the services tries to acquire another instance of its type with *different* settings object.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyService2 {
    public MyService2(MyService2Settings settings, <service-dependent list of dependencies filled by Windsor>)
    {
        this.uplink = settings.Counter == 1
            ? new AnotherUplink()
            : new RecursiveUplink(
                container.Resolve<MyService2>(new {
                    settings = new MyService2Settings(settings.Counter - 1)
                });
    }
}
```

This recursive dependency chain is finite (and is about 6 instances deep), but Windsor throws an exception when the first service tries to get another one, stating that it's a circular dependency.

I've advertised all the services as having `Transient` lifestyles and requesting them with custom parameters. Can I at least specify the maximum allowed depth of the recursion? Or am I missing another way I can do it?

*another requirement*: I can't use typed factories, because I've got quite many different types of those services, so generating many factory interfaces individually for those services would be undesired.

Answer (score 1):

> container doesn't have any of the MyServiceXSettings types registered,
>   so the only way to get a service is to resolve it from container like
>   this:

You may also use a dedicated SubResolver or a DependsOn during component registration.

Executing code in a constructor(rather than a simply variable assignement) is a smell, even worst using the container: it should never leak in the application layer.

At the first sight, it seems you are using the settings only to choose the proper component within the constructor: that should be done at CompositionRoot, using a TypedFactory or also by [naming convention](http://kozmic.net/2009/04/09/convention-based-dependency-injection-with-castle-microkernelwindsor/)(you may have multiple component registered for same intercace, but a given parameter name drives the component selection)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610935/579817), I went with lazy resolution.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents single component instance producer.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TComponent">type of the component to create</typeparam>
public interface IComponentCreator<TComponent>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the created component.
    /// </summary>
    TComponent Component { get; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates the component only when it's first requested.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TComponent">type of the component to create</typeparam>
public class LazyCreator<TComponent> : IComponentCreator<TComponent>
{
    private readonly Func<TComponent> creatingFunction;
    private bool created;
    private TComponent component;

    public LazyCreator(Func<TComponent> creatingFunction)
    {
        this.creatingFunction = creatingFunction;
    }

    public TComponent Component
    {
        get
        {
            if (!created)
            {
                component = creatingFunction();
                created = true;
            }

            return component;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns already created component.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TComponent">type of the component</typeparam>
public class ComponentContainer<TComponent> : IComponentCreator<TComponent>
{
    private readonly TComponent component;

    public ComponentContainer(TComponent component)
    {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public TComponent Component
    {
        get { return component; }
    }
}
```